# Can level 49 be used for STRING purpose

Tags: cobol

As I'm new to cobol, please help me with the below piece of code.

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

01 BAS-REC.

      02 INPT-REC.
      49 INPT-LEN   PIC S9(4) COMP.
      49 INPT-TEXT  PIC X(150).

   02 INPT1-REC.

      49 INPT1-LEN   PIC S9(4) COMP.
      49 INPT1-TEXT  PIC X(150).

   02 INPT2-REC.

      49 INPT2-LEN   PIC S9(4) COMP.
      49 INPT2-TEXT  PIC X(150).

77  VAR1   PIC  X(5) VALUE 'APT'.

77  NUM1   PIC  9(1).
```

I'm using the level 49 for character varying here (to truncate trailing spaces)

Then I have cursor fetch.

After few modification under `PROCEDURE DIVISION` I'm doing the below.

```
PERFORM UNTIL SQLCODE=100

PERFORM VARYING NUM1 FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL NUM1=6

STRING INPT-REC DELIMITED BY '  ',' ',
       VAR1 DELIMITED BY '  ',' '
       NUM1 DELIMITED BY '  ' INTO INPT2-REC

EXEC SQL

insert query here (which will run 5 times) 

END-EXEC

END- PERFORM

END- PERFORM
```

---

but in the table the data got inserted only once but it shold have got inserted 5 times and also the `INPT2-REC` hasn't been concatenated. The `INPT2 -REC` just contains the value of `INPT-REC` alone

My question is this a special characteristic of level 49 or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: I can't really parsse this code - there's two `PERFORM`s but only one `END-PERFORM`, NUM1 is undefined, the second perform looks like a `PERFORM VARYING`, but there is no `VARYING`,... As to your question: Nothing sepcial about level 49 except that it's the last "normal" level number.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I think there is something more specific about this level number. I think we may not use it for STRING purpose and it won't work inside PERFORM VARYING. These are my doubts

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you use `INPT-REC2` as a host-variable for a `VARCHAR`-field you will only see the part from `INPT-REC` since you never update the length-field: it still contains the length it was assigned from `INPT-REC`.

So you'll have to somehow get the actual length of `INPT2-TEXT` (e.g. `INSPECT` the `REVERSE` of `INPT2-TEXT` for `LEADING SPACES`) and move it to `INPT2-LENGTH` before your `EXEC SQL`.

As I already said in my comment: there is nothing special about level `49` - you could as well use `48`, `33`,`30` or `05` with the same results. The samples in the DB2 manual probably use `49` since it is the last valid level-number without any special meaning, so it is least likely to cause problems with any level-numbers already used in the program.

As for the query being executed only once: in your loop you are varying `NUM1` but are checking whether `I=6` - since we don't see `I` anywhere in your example I can only guess that it is already equal to 6 upon entering the loop.

Comment: Thanks piet.t . I'' try this. Can you please try me why did the query got executed only once. I displayed the INPT2-REC and it printed all the concatenated values.

Comment: @Subinraj.S ah yes, I forgot the loop-issue. I added my guess to the answer.

Comment: but I checked printing INPT2-REC within the loop and it got printed 5 times

Comment: @Subinraj.S then there seems to be a different issue with the code you actually ran as oppesed to the code you posted - a single period can severly mess up any porgram logic.

Comment: To be precise, below is how the logic is:.                                                   Perform open query
Perform fetch query
Perform until sql=100
   Perform 1 by 1 until 6
       String statement
       Insert statement
END- PERFORM
   Fetch next record
END- PERFORM
Perform close query

Comment: As I said - a single period that isn#t  in the right place can mess all that up. Also: Are you sure the insert is executed only once? Why?

Comment: Embedded SQL seems to treat level 49 special.  `However, you can declare a varying-length character string, which must be level 49.`  From https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_hoststructurescobol.html

Answer (score 1):

Level 49 can be treated specially when Embedded SQL is involved, depending on system; this text is copied from the IBM Knowledge Center

Host structure declarations in COBOL must satisfy the following requirements:

COBOL host structures can have a maximum of two levels, even though the host structure might occur within a structure with multiple levels. However, you can declare a varying-length character string, which must be level 49.

A host structure name can be a group name whose subordinate levels name elementary data items.

If you are using the DB2® precompiler, do not declare host variables or host structures on any subordinate levels after one of the following items:

```
    A COBOL item that begins in area A
    Any SQL statement (except SQL INCLUDE)
    Any SQL statement within an included member
```

When the DB2 precompiler encounters one of the preceding items in a host structure, it considers the structure to be complete.

---

So, this seems like a little implementation detail (level 49 for var char) that may spill over into other implementations of COBOL ESQL.  Like many details buried in systems, *Knowing that would require knowing that.*

This particular detail is news to me as of a few minutes ago.

Looking more just now, this came up in the esqlOC contribution for GnuCOBOL recently.  A level 49 specific tweak to ensure there was no need to worry about little end big end storage between host and service.  So it seems to be a thing.

And an answer to the original question is; depends on compiler environment and ESQL preprocessor, but yeah maybe level 49 fields can be used for VARCHAR.

Comment: Good catch about that level 49 issue - didn't know about that either. It really seems to be a preprocessor implementation detail. Perhaps @Allan Kielstra could shed some light on this? Or is this more of a topic for IBM's DB2 guys?